# Need help in training workflow with personalized training page

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have a training workflow requirement where the administrator uploads a document to a document library, which will initiate a training workflow. The workflow will consist of specifying which documents the users have to read, the due date , select affected users from AD, choose whether to send the users an email or not to say that training is available. Also choose when a user finishes this training (through another workflow discussed below) , send an email to Admin saying the user has completed the training. 
The admin should have a "View" where he/she can see which users have completed the training and which haven't.

The users need to have a webpage on Sharepoint where they can see the training assigned to them. They click on say "Begin training", it will point to the document that admin uploaded, they will read it and the next step would be to acknowledge that they have read the document and mark training as finished. Depending on whether the admin had set up the notification, an email will be sent to the admin that the user has finished the training. Most likely admin won't need this feature but just in case.

I am a beginner in designing workflows. I will need to know how do I get started with this ?

Comment: What version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Its Sharepoint Foundation 2010.

Comment: Can anyone answer this ? I just need the directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do I download SharePoint Designer.

Here is the SharePoint Designer download page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573

After you install SharePoint Designer, open your site and create a workflow related to that list. You can do everything you described using SharePoint Designer workflows. Here's how you can get started:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx

http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/getting-started-sharepoint-2010-creating-workflows-with-sharepoint-designer/10ts7flgd

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the links. I already have gone through it and also have the designer 2010. Can I also show the users, their training status and training history ? How that could be done ? Again the workflow using the designer ?

Comment: I would look into making a status list and have a default view filtered to the user logged in, that describes the classes they took and completed. You can update this status list directly from the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

if you would consider a 3rd party add-on developed by my company, then you may want to take a look at DocRead for SharePoint.

As a training publisher, DocRead allows you to :

1. Upload a document to a document library
2. Assign one or more group(s) or Audience(s) to it.
3. Allocate the members of the group a number of days to complete it by.
4. Create a task for every user in the group.
5. Track who has completed their training, and who has not (via Reports)

As a user who needs to do the training you are :

1. Able to view all your training tasks via a web part.
2. Read the document (word, pdf, web page, wiki, etc).
3. Get notified in e-mail.
4. Confirm the training and get a receipt / certificate.

This blog post shows an example of how to [distribute a training video with SharePoint and DocRead](http://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/policy-management/2012/12/13/how-to-distribute-a-training-video-with-docread-for-sharepoint) :

Hope this helps.

Many thanks
Mark